# Expo Print works in Expo go but not in build apk

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use the expo print api to be able to generate and  print a receipt, however on button press it shows the preview on development (the expo go app) but on the build apk, nothing is shown.
Here is my implementation:

This hook generates my html data:

```
  export const DynamicTable = async () => {   
   const receipthtml = `
       <html>
       <head>
       <style>
       </style>
       <body> 
       //some html
       </body> 
       </html>`
       return receipthtml;
        }
```

function to do the printing

```
   const dynamiccontainer =DynamicTable(); //accessing the html data
   const printReceipt = async () => {   
   await Print.printAsync({
   html:await dynamiccontainer,
   height: 1754,
   width: 1240,
  });
 };



 <Button
        text="Print Receipt"
        backgroundColor="#0091ea"
        rippleColor="#367588"
        borderRadius={8}
        paddingHorizontal={5}
        icon={faPrint}
        onPress={printReceipt}
        height={50}
      ></Button>
```

I don't seem to find anything wrong with my implementation

Answer (score 0):

check if you have a base64 image, the problem is that the eas build command doesn't upload certain files. In the case of images, if they aren't used as splah or icon, they aren't found and the print dosen't open.
Then it will work in expo go, but when you generate the app it won't anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not being able to use Print in Release mode.
Analyzing the logs a little using `adb logcat,` I identified that the file path was not found, even though it was being imported correctly.
The alternative that my team and I followed was to use the images within the page that performed the Print request, so that the path of the images was forced to be found. And then with CSS we gave a `display: "none"` to not appear on the screen next to the button.
That way we were able to use Print, even with local images.